# Jquery Drag and drop not working in chrome and ie9

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am using the drag and drop feature of jquery . its works fine in firefox but fails in chrome and ie9 .

Below are the version of jquery lib i am using :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="language" content="en" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/js/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.min.js"></script>
```

Here my drag and dro code :

```
$(function() {
    $(".item").draggable({
            revert: true
    });
    $("#mail-circle-wraper").droppable({
            tolerance: 'touch',
            over: function() {   

                   $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
            },
            out: function() {           
                $(".item").draggable({
                    revert: false
            });
                    $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
            },
            drop: function() {
                    bootbox.confirm("Add this person to circle ?", function(confirmed) {

                        // do somthing
                    });

                    $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
            }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can we see your code for the drag and drop and what the specific error it is that your getting?

Comment: is this happening because of the version of the jquery and ui ?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your jquery libraries to these:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.21/jquery-ui.min.js
```

Let me know if this works by any chance.

Answer (score 1):

please add the following 2 library because its working fine in all browser. I have tested it.

[Jquery.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js)

[Jquery-ui.min.js](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.23/jquery-ui.min.js)